# What is a prefix set?

Tags: formal-languages, automata

I am trying to understand the following definition of prefix set - "A prefix set is a language $A \subseteq \Sigma^*$" such that no element of A is a prefix of any other element of A.

I came across a similar phrase in Li-Vitányi's book, "no element in the set is a proper prefix of another element in the set".

Can someone please elaborate on this? Perhaps an example will help me understand it. I couldn't find the explanation for this on Wikipedia or on Math.SE

Comment: Thank you. Let me elaborate then.

Comment: In general, a word $w_1$ is a prefix of a word $w_2$ if  the first $n$ letters of $w_2$ are $w_1$ for some $n.$ So $abc$ is a prefix of $abcdef$ but not a prefix of $ababc.$

Comment: Ah, it makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A word $p$ is a *prefix* of a word $u$ if there exists a word $s$ (possibly the empty word) such that $u = ps$. Let $A$ be an alphabet. A subset $P$ of $A^*$ is *prefix* if the conditions $u, v \in P$ and $u$ prefix of $v$ imply $u = v$. For instance, $\{aa, ab, b\}$ is prefix, but $\{aa, ba, b\}$ is not since $b$ is a prefix of $ba$.